# Update 'changing' variables every time PS1 is called, i.e. every new prompt

Tags: bash, prompt

The reason I need to be able to do this, is to have 'updating' variables in my PS1. I'd like to have my prompt span across the entire width of the terminal, not wrapping around or going down to a new line. For this, I already found a way to get it working, but this method requires me to reload bash every time. Here's what I would like it to look like:

```
|me::awesome| --------------------------------------------------------- ~/.config/awesome
$
```

After that, when I cd into a new directory, it will look like this:

```
|me::themes| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
------ ~/.config/awesome/themes
$
```

But when I then run

```
exec bash
```

it will successfully change all values and look like this:

```
|me::themes| --------------------------------------------------- ~/.config/awesome/themes
$
```

So I'm looking for a way to incorporate changing variables into my PS1 variable, which I would want updated every time a new prompt is called. This is what my .bashrc looks like at the moment:

```
mytest=$PWD
mynext="$(basename $PWD)"
mylength=$((${#mytest}+${#mynext}))
length=$(($mylength+6))
PS1='|me::\W| $(printf "\\u2500%.0s" $(seq $length $(tput cols))) \w\n\$'
```

I've also tried putting the the variables into a separate shell script file, and running that within my PS1, as follows:

```
#/home/me/.PS1.sh
mytest=$PWD
mynext="$(basename $PWD)"
mylength=$((${#mytest}+${#mynext}))
length=$(($mylength+6))
echo "|me::\W| $(printf "\\u2500%.0s" $(seq $length $(tput cols))) \w\n\$"

#/home/me/.bashrc
PS1=$(/home/me/.PS1.sh)
```

Answer (score 1):

your variables get evaluated only the first time , you must put them inside the ps1 to be treated literally ffirst time and get evaluated after command execution .

```
PS1='|me::\W| $( mytest=$PWD;mynext="${PWD##*/}";  mylength=$((${#mytest}+${#mynext})) ; length=$(($mylength+6)) ; printf "\\u2500%.0s" $(seq $length $(tput cols))) \w\n\$'
```

you can change only 6 if you added stuff to ps1